# Can I keep specific header one page?

Tags: header-footer

I m working on auto report and I need to put some specific header on specific page specially after `\newpage`. How can I control it?

```
\\newpage 
<header 1>
for rest of pages
<header 2>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define the header for the specific page and then for the rest.
An example how to define such a header is given for example at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout.
There are also packages for defining fancy headers, for example `fancyhdr`.